# Interact with SQL database using only Python 2.4

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite, web-hosting

I have a website on an Australian webhost. I have designed my website to allow people to login & their login details are stored in an SQLite3 database. I interact with the SQLite3 database using pythons SQLite3 module(found only in python2.5 & up)

**My Problem:** the webhost runs Python 2.4 so I cannot communicate with(query or modify) my SQLite3 database. The webhost will not allow me to install my own version of python or upload modules unless I upgrade to VPS.

What do you think are my options to still be able to work/interface with my SQL database? Do you know of way to interact with a SQL database using python modules from Python 2.4 or earlier?

**Do you know of a python 2.4 module that will let me interact with an SQL database(can be MySQL, SQLite, etc.)?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python MySQL Module, called MySQLDB, which supports Python 2.3-2.7: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

The User Guide can be found here: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pysqlite](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite). It is the same module as in the newer python versions and I have used it no prob in 2.4 before.